# NDSolve WhenEvent and If conditional with multiple actions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to impose multiple action based on two conditions I have an `If` statement inside a `WhenEevent`.

The problem I am facing is that I can only impose one action `a(t)` or `b(t)` if I impose the two action the code doesn't recognize it.

`a(t)` and `b(t)` are discrete variables that I want them to change every single time `x(t)==0` and `x'(t)<0` as they accumulate everytime they change as shown in the `WhenEvent` function. Should I use the `Block` function?

Is there an alternative way of imposing multiple conditions inside the `If` function because it only seem capable of doing 1 action at a time. Thank you

```
IC = {x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, a[0] == 10, b[0] == 0.1};

sol=NDSolve[
   {x''[t] + b[t] x'[t] + a[t] x[t] == 0,
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, If[x'[t] < 0, a[t] -> 3 - x[t] && b[t] -> 0.1 - x'[t]]],
    IC}, 
   {x[t], a[t], x'[t], b[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, DiscreteVariables -> {a[t], b[t]}]
Plot[{x[t], a[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 5}]
Plot[{x'[t], b[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An action in [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) should be a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) or a keyword string (see docs), or a list of these. Instead of `If` to impose a condition on an event, use `And`: `WhenEvent[event && condition, action]`.

```
IC = {x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, a[0] == 10, b[0] == 0.1};

sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + b[t] x'[t] + a[t] x[t] == 0,
   WhenEvent[x[t] == 0 && x'[t] < 0, {a[t] -> 3 - x[t], b[t] -> 0.1 - x'[t]}],
   IC},
  {x[t], a[t], x'[t], b[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {a[t], b[t]}]
Plot[{x[t], a[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 5}]
Plot[{x'[t], b[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you I understand that but I am wanting to do it with If instead of only WhenEvent

Answer (score 1):

Inside If, separate statements with a semicolon, not &&, the code does something. But, it is wrong, and I don't yet know why it is giving wrong output.

```
 IC = {x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, a[0] == 10, b[0] == 1/10};
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + b[t] x'[t] + a[t] x[t] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, 
     If[x'[t] < 0, a[t] -> 3 - x[t]; b[t] -> 0.1 - x'[t]]], IC}, {x, 
    a, b}, {t, 0, 5}, DiscreteVariables -> {a, b}];
Plot[{x[t], a[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 5}]
Plot[{x'[t], b[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 5}]
```

It looks like a sequence of actions written within If command doesn't work well, thus using two WhenEvent makes it work.

```
IC = {x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, a[0] == 10, b[0] == 1/10};
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + b[t] x'[t] + a[t] x[t] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, If[x'[t] < 0, b[t] -> 0.1 - x'[t]]], 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, If[x'[t] < 0, a[t] -> 3 - x[t]]], IC}, {x, a,
     b}, {t, 0, 5}, DiscreteVariables -> {a, b}];
Plot[{x[t], a[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 5}]
Plot[{x'[t], b[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: What makes you think it works? The discrete variables `a[t]` and `b[t]` should change at the same time, but they do not.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I made a mistake, I did not check the result. Sorry about this. I don't know why it doesn't work though, trying to figure it out.

Comment: I think the reason the first answer does not work is that in the value of the `CompoundExpression` in the `If` statement, `a[t] -> 3 - x[t]; b[t] -> 0.1 - x'[t]`, is the last expression `b[t] -> 0.1 - x'[t]`; any expressions before a semicolon are ignored except for any side effects they have through setting a variable's value, but a `Rule` such as `a[t] -> 3 - x[t]` has no such side effect. That said, `WhenEvent` does rewrite the code, so you can't always count on things being as they seem. You might try a `List` instead of `CompoundExpression`: `{ a[t] -> 3 - x[t], b[t] -> 0.1 - x'[t]}`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much for this CompoundExpression. It works well, and resolved few issues for me.